# Woocommerce- Retrieve only instock products when insert CROSS and UP SELL PRODUCT

Tags: woocommerce

when i create a product, i need to add cross sell and up sell products, but when i start to digit i want that system shows to me only product available.
How do this? I tried something like this [How to hide out of stock products from Cross-sells and Upsells products in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611726/how-to-hide-out-of-stock-products-from-cross-sells-and-upsells-products-in-wooco)

```
<?php if ( ! $cross_sell->is_in_stock() && ! $cross_sell->backorders_allowed() ) : continue; endif; ?>
```

but is referred to product frontend page
How to do this?
To the admin: i cannot add some type of code because i did not find anything about this!

Comment: What is the difference between your question and the answer you referred to? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). | _"To the admin"_ - 
who or what do you mean by this?

Comment: There is no admin here, it's a community. We have moderators.